# How to close AVD Manager in eclipse Luna

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I am now using eclipse luna(earlier used is juno i shifted system and now use this ).Juno provides a cancel button but this is a new envoirnment for me.Inside this i was trying to create emulator.But i cannot..After that i am looking to close it,but no close button (cancel button)found at here.Can anyone please help me how to close it?

[image]

Any answer will be really helpfull.

Advance Thanks

Comment: press esc and it will be closed .... ;)

Comment: This is not problem of eclipse, this is the problem of the theme you are using for UBUNTU

Comment: thanks for your kind information sharing pankajkumar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey just click on 'esc' button. It will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Click the 'Delete' button after you highlite one of the avd simulators.